# Can't find RackMonkey::CGI module

Tags: perl

For some odd reason... Rackmonkey::CGI.pm is not being picked up... what am I doing incorrectly here?

Thanks!

```
Can't locate RackMonkey/CGI.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at ./rackmonkey.pl line 34. 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./rackmonkey.pl line 34.

blah blah > locate CGI.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CGI.pm

use RackMonkey::CGI;
use RackMonkey::Engine;
use RackMonkey::Error;
```

Comment: Tone down the exclamation points :)

Comment: It looks like a non-CPAN vendor installed a horked version of CGI.pm that isn't the standard one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `Rackmonkey/CGI.pm` in your path. In fact, I bet none of the [`Rackmonkey::*` modules](http://rackmonkey.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rackmonkey/rackmonkey/trunk/www/RackMonkey/) are in your path.

Here's how to fix it…if your `/www/RackMonkey` directory is inside `/blahblah/`, then add:

```
use lib '/blahblah/www/RackMonkey';
```

above your other `use` lines.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all.  There's no RackMonkey component in `CGI.pm`'s path.  Ie - a bare `use CGI;` would work here because `/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8` is in `@INC`.  `CGI.pm` would have to live under `/some/directory/in/@INC/RackMonkey` in order for `use RackMonkey::CGI;` to work out of the box.

See `perldoc perlvar` under `@INC`, and `perldoc -f require` for more info about module inclusion behavior.

Comment: RackMonkey::CGI.pm isn't the same as CGI.pm (see http://rackmonkey.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rackmonkey/rackmonkey/trunk/www/RackMonkey/CGI.pm?view=markup), so `use CGI` wouldn't work at all here.

Comment: Look back at the question.  `locate CGI.pm` shows a `CGI.pm` which is in `@INC`, so while it may not duplicate the *functionality* of `RackMonkey::CGI`, the `use` *would* in fact work as I said.

Comment: You're right, Brian. Since Clustermagnet seems confused by the difference between CGI.pm and RackMonkey/CGI.pm, it may be better to give him or her a less ambiguous example, e.g. `use Test`.